# Create multiple static objects in C++

Tags: c++, embedded, arm

Long story short, I need to create lots of objects within a function. Is it possible to do so without copying and pasting?

Basically, the effect I'm after is this

```
class foo() { .... }

void bar()
{
    static foo obj1;
    static foo obj2;
    static foo obj3;
    ...
    ...
    static foo obj501;
}
```

Any help is much appreciated :)

Update : It seems my motivation behind the question is required :)

I'm trying to create a test case to test a limitation we have on our implementation of atexit(), to be run on an ARM artchitecture. The limitation is that there is a fixed number of static objects which can be registered with __aeabi_atexit at the moment (let's say, for argument sake, that number is 500). If more objects are registered, the function simply returns (without any error message), causing a silent failure, not very nice. Now, I have fixed the "pointless return" bit in the implementation of atexit(), but need to test the fix, and in order to do so, I need to create atleast 500 static objects.

Comment: Yep, but an array or vector won't do in this case, it needs to be individual static objects I'm afraid :(

Comment: This is to work on an embedded system, and there is a defect in one of the fundamental functions which puts an upper limit on the number of static objects which can be registered with it. Using an array doesn't help in that case, since the compiler optimizes away the information which needs to be passed to that function

Comment: So you're asking us to help you work around a bug for a compiler which you haven't mentioned? Good luck with that.

Comment: Doh, deleting answer because the only part that remains valid is questioning why do these objects need to be static?

Comment: 'cos they need to be registered with __aeabi_atexit(), which is the ARM function which registers all static objects

Comment: @NullPointer: What you are doing is very platform-specific. Can you please provide some details about your platform, and why you are trying to do this? Please edit these into your question.

Comment: can you use boost preprocessor? if so, there is a macro provided which can repeat another macro a given number of times...

Comment: hmm, that might just the thing I'm looking for. I'll have a look in there, thanks Nim

Comment: Write a script in some other language (Perl, Tcl etc.) to create the function for you.

Comment: Yea, looks like this might be my final resort. Hmmm, now that I think of it, I guess this is just a 5min job in Perl, but I didn't think of it :)

Comment: Wow - talk about a "too localized" question...  The effort in just asking and clarifying the question seems to have completely eclipsed just doing the one-off copy-n-pasting for this corner case test scenario.

Comment: I agree Michael, but quoting southpark.. "I learnt something today" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do it with recursive template functions:

```
template <int N> void makeStatic() {
    static foo s_foo;
    makeStatic<N-1>();
};

template <> void makeStatic<0>() {
    static foo s_foo; // comment this out to get 512, otherwise you get 513 objects. :)
};

void bar() { makeStatic<512>(); }
```

Answer (score 8):

Copying and pasting isn't a bad solution for a one-off test like this. To optimize it, you should reselect the entire block before copying, that way you double the size of the block each time - you can reach 512 objects with only 8 pastes.

The next problem is to give each object a unique name. For that we turn to the lowly macro:

```
#define STATIC_OBJECT static foo obj##__LINE__

STATIC_OBJECT;
STATIC_OBJECT;
...
```

Comment: Cool, this should do it. Thanks a lot Mark :)

Comment: Or better yet, let Vi do the pasting, took me 5 seconds to get it all done, thanks for your help

Comment: @NullPointer, I've been using Windows far too long - is the command something like `501P`? Anyway I'm glad it worked out for you.

Comment: yep, 501p did the trick. Btw, you can get Vi for windows too, infact, thats what I'm using. Google gVim

Comment: @NullPointer, I actually have vim as part of Cygwin, but I never use it - I was never a power user, and I've become much more comfortable with Windows editors.

Comment: @Mark: Yeah, in windows, I'd just hold down ctrl-v and watch the line number count. :)

Answer (score 3):

What if you did...

```
template <int N> struct HasStaticMember : public HasStaticMember<N - 1> {
    static foo mFoo;
};

template <> struct HasStaticMember<1> {
    static foo mFoo;
};

void bar() { HasStaticMember<501> foo; }
```

Edit: VS2010 didn't like 501 template recursions.  You might still have to do something like put 5 variables per struct and use 101 template args instead...  See the comments below for other suggestions.

Comment: +1 for recursive templates. Note that you might need to declare these static members outside the struct/class, so it might be better to declare a function (still templated over int) that calls itself (still with -1) instead.

Answer (score 2):

..adding as an answer from comments above, incase it's useful to anyone else I guess...

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/repetition/repeat.hpp>

#define DECL(z, n, text) text ## n;

struct bar{};

void foo()
{
  BOOST_PP_REPEAT(5, DECL, static bar temp)
}

int main(void)
{
  foo();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nim, will certainly keep this one in mind for the future :)

Comment: there is one limitation - can only repeat up to 256 times! :(

Comment: There's always a catch eh? ;).

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you want to do this. Can't you just use arrays or vectors instead?

If you really want to do this, you can try using the token pasting operator (##)

Comment: I can't use arrays 'cos I'm basically stress testing the atexit() function (for ARM), for which I need to register each individual object with it.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use an array or vector?

```
class foo() { .... }

void bar()
{  
    // Using an array:
    static foo obj_arr[502];

    // or

    // Using a vector
    // Size given in the constructor to tell it how many objects you're going to need
    // This may or may not be needed depending on how how your code is set up, since 
    // vectors automatically resize when elements are added to them. 
    static std::vector<foo> obj_vec(502); 
}
```